# Verify SSL for local computers

Tags: apache-httpd, ssl, certificates

I have a small business network and for this network, one computer is DHCP-, DNS- and web server.
It uses local domains like machinary.ao or resources.ao

I'd like to use ssl. 
Computers and network don't connected to the internet, everything is local only and nothing goes out or comes in.

I enabled SSL in apache and I created some certificates for it.
The problem is: The browsers don't accept the SSL certificate, all browsers say it is not trusted.

Why is that and what should i do? I want to use SSL for security, but how can I make it trusted?

I don't want to pay SSL certificates amount of money for nothing. I already have local network and I want to make it more secure.

How can I make local Certificate Authority to sign my certificate?
Or what should I do?

Answer (score 0):

Your network is small and not connected to the internet.
What risk are you're trying to mitigate by using SSL?

Using SSL on an internal network adds a layer of security, but (depending on the network use) only for a (very) small part of all network traffic.

If any part of your network is wireless and you don't trust the security of your WLAN, then you may consider connecting the wireless clients over VPN.

Other than that, if you're afraid of someone wiretapping your network, you have a problem that's several orders of magnitude bigger. In that case, you need physical security countermeasures like perimeter security or security guards...

Comment: If you don't want to be rude, then just don't do it. Don't swear either, it doesn't contribute to the discussion. Plus, you completely ignore the context in which this question was asked. The OP wants to secure his / her network, using https instead of http only adds a fig leaf of security instead of achieving what the OP *really* wants.

Answer (score 0):

Premise:  if you have created a certificate, you have a (personal) certification authority and I suppose that you have already signed your certificate (during the creation phase).

In a few words:
the main problem is to identify the owner of a specific certificate. 
Every browser have a set of trusted certificates emitted by trusted certification authorities. When you open a website with https protocol your browser check if the certificate of this website is signed by a known certification authority (using the certificate of this CA). In this way you have a big and trusted company that tell you  :"ok the certificate is good and valid".
In your case the problem is that you aren't a CA. So the browser inform you of the possible risk. 
To solve you have to tell to every browser that you use that you certificate is good (search something like "add an exception" in the page with certificate warning).

Answer (score 0):

As said above you can manually tell every single browser to create a exception.
But that is probably not what you are looking for.
Of course you can be your own certificate authority, bigger companies for example use such a internal public key infrastructure.
I can't tell you how to do that exactly but here are some links to get you started:
https://help.ubuntu.com/lts/serverguide/certificates-and-security.html
https://askubuntu.com/questions/73287/how-do-i-install-a-root-certificate
I guess it is not to hard to figure out how to do this if you have at least an idea of how PKIs and CAs work.